# Dynamically replaced row in table shows error with already present rows

Tags: jquery

My html contains a table have the structure like this

```
<table id="sample">
 <tr class="new_input_field">
   <td><input type="text" class="first_input" /></td>
   <td><input type="text" class="second_input" /></td>
   <td><a href="#" class="first_link">Button1</td>
   <td><a href="#" class="second_link">Button2</td>
 </tr><tr class="new_input_field">
   <td><input type="text" class="first_input" /></td>
   <td><input type="text" class="second_input" /></td>
   <td><a href="#" class="first_link">Button1</td>
   <td><a href="#" class="second_link">Button2</td>
 </tr>
 <tr class="new_input_field">
   <td><input type="text" class="first_input" /></td>
   <td><input type="text" class="second_input" /></td>
   <td><a href="#" class="first_link">Button1</td>
   <td><a href="#" class="second_link">Button2</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

And for each row in my jquery the values for first_input and second_input value change triggers a call to server and that row will be replaced by like this.

```
<tr id="AIK">
<td>some content</td>
<td>some other content</td>
<td><a href="#" class="first_link">Button1</td>
<td><a href="#" class="second_link">Button1</td>
</tr>
```

My Problem is when i click the buttons in dynamically replaced row should show alert. I gave jquery

```
$('#sample tr td a.first_link').click(function () {
 trid = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id');
 if(trid.length > 0) { alert("Swap out will come soon"); }
});
```

This works fine for newly replaced row and shows error with remaining two rows as

```
TypeError: Result of expression 'trid' [undefined] is not an object.
```

The buttons should be enable for newly replaced rows only. How can i solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to assign `id` first to closest `tr` and then try like following:

```
$('#sample tr td a.first_link').click(function () {
 var trid = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id');
 if(trid.length > 0) { alert("Swap out will come soon"); }
});
```

if you don't put id then you can try:

```
var trid = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id') || '';
```

Comment: I assigned the id to newly replaced row. But not for other rows. Shall i need to give empty id as <tr id="">?

Comment: @Rajeswari I think if you use my second `trid` assign method you don't have to assign empty `id`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're dealing with dynamically added table rows, you shouldn't be using `$.click`. Instead, you should be using delegation via the `$.on` method:

```
$("table#sample").on("click", "a.first_link", function(){
  trid = $(this).closest("tr").attr("id");
  if ( trid.length > 0 )
    alert( "Swap out will come soon." );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using,

```
$('#sample tr td a.first_link').live('click',function...
```

instead of

```
$('#sample tr td a.first_link').click(function...
```